# how to change image background when uiscrollview being scrolled?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

as i already stated in the title above, i want to change the image background animatedly fade out and replace by another image while the `uiscrollview` being scrolled. my `uiviewcontroller` hierarchy is simple :

**uiviewcontroller**--->**uiimageview**--->**uiscrollview**

additional info on uiscrollview :
1. my uiscrollview contains a simple `uilabel` and some `uiimageview`(just small part as a subview of `uiscrollview`). 
2. paging enabled
3. scroll horizontally (if that matter)

so, can anyone here please help me how to accomplished this method? just a simple clue will be much appreciated since im still a beginner but i want to learn from all masters here.

thank you so much for all help and wish you a good day.

Comment: How do you create the image background? Do yu use a UIImageView stretched across the view?, or do you set it progrmmatically?

Comment: yes, i use uiimageview stretched fill the view controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is also another way of doing this (neater IMO):

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView 
{
  UIImage * toImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myname.png"];
  [UIView transitionWithView:self.view
                duration:5.0f
                options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                animations:^{
                self.imageView.image = toImage;
                } completion:nil];
}
```

**EDIT**

For multiple images/pages and switching back and forth between, It would be better to use the

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

That way you won't have any conflicts when changing between pages.

To get the images to change accordingly, you would use a `switch` statement, which also means you would have to associate your pages with numbers. Since Apple did not include this as a property of UIScrollView, you have to get the data yourself using:

```
int page = scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.frame.size.width;
```

And then to add all of this together in a nice method:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    int page = scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.frame.size.width;

    //Use the switch to set the variable (toImage) depending on the page
    switch (page){
                    case 0:  UIImage * toImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imageOne.png"];
                    break;
                    case 1:  UIImage * toImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imageTwo.png"];
                    break;
                    case 2:  UIImage * toImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imageThree.png"];
                    break;
                    case 3:  UIImage * toImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imageFour.png"];
                    break;
                 }

        //use the variable (toImage) and perform the transition from the current image

        [UIView transitionWithView:self.view
                                  duration:5.0f
                                  options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                                  animations:^{
                                  self.imageView.image = toImage;
                                  } completion:nil];
}
```

I haven't tested the above code, but from my knowledge of C and Obj C, it should work.

Comment: thanks captjak, this one works. but how if i have like 4 pages(paging enabled) in uiscrollview and i want each page represent different image?

Comment: @redribbon, check my edit. Any more code and your paying me ;)

Comment: woww, thank you so much my friend. this code really help me to achieve the effect. still need a few works but easy. so yes, im using didenddecelerating instead of did scroll but thanks for the clue. also you have to start from case 0 instead of case 1 or your second page wont change, and the last one is in each case you have to add curly bracket or the code just wont work :D ( ex: case 1: { } break;..........ok, i wont bothered you anymore since i dont want to get a paper check payment from you hehehehee :p

Comment: Yes, that is correct on the numbering, since the index starts at 0. I'm glad it works!

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can try this code

Step 1 : Add UIScrollViewDelegate to your UIViewController

Step 2 : Attache the UIScrollView delegate on your UIViewController (XIB or StoryBoard)

Step 3 : In implementation controller implements this delegate methode

```
 -(void) scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                     animations:^{
                         [self<UIImageView> setAlpha:0];
                     }
     ];

    [self<UIImageView> setImage:<Your second image>]

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                     animations:^{
                         [self<UIImageView> setAlpha:1];
                     }
     ];

}
```

perhaps that the scrollViewDidScroll: delegate it more judicious have to test